# Splitting NSString into NSArray on component '\n'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to split a `NSString` into a `NSArray`, and it's proving difficult even though this is normally an easy task. I'm receiving data, from my Python server and forming a `NSString` on the iPhone client. I noticed sometimes when I receive multiple messages from my Python server I would `NSLog` a string like:

```
Project: textOne
textTwo
```

After adding the string into a `NSArray` and calling `NSLog` on that array the string would show:

```
Project: (
    "textOne\ntextTwo\n"
)
```

After playing with code:

```
[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

[str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
```

I have managed to produce `NSArray`'s with content:

```
Project: (
    "textOne",
    textTwo
)
```

And

```
Project: (
    "textOne",
    textTwo,
    ""
)
```

I **cannot** produce a `NSArray` with content:

```
Project: (
        textOne,
        textTwo
    )
```

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What does the unquoted `textTwo` mean?  It's not a string?

Comment: It doesn't count as a string, and I'm not sure why it's being produced

Comment: @JohnBale: What *is* it, if not a string?

Comment: It probably is a string, it's just NSLog that sometimes doesn't use quotes.

Comment: In general, `NSArray.description` (which is what NSLog uses) only quotes strings if they contain an embedded "odd" character.  In your above example it's not clear why "textOne" is being quoted -- perhaps because of an embedded blank in the real example you're paraphrasing for us?

Comment: Yes, that was my assumption upon looking at the data, but John asserts that it "doesn't count as a string," which is very odd.

Comment: John's assertion is incorrect.

Comment: My bad, textTwo is actually ok, it's textOne, the one quotations which is actually unusual, as stated by Hot Licks

Comment: I think the unusual character it is detecting is the '\n', which is why it shows "" sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Trim your string before separating into components using [stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a) to prevent empty components at the end or beginning.

```
NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmed = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:separatorSet];
[trimmed componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet];
```

This won't prevent empty strings in the middle of your array.

Another solution would be to filter out any undesired strings after separating into components.

Comment: +1 consider whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet for the trimming, then just newline for the splitting.